# Circle and Rectangle Collision Android

Tags: java, android, graphics, collision-detection, physics

I have a ball bouncing on my screen and there is a static rectangle that it can collide with and should bounce off of. I have already figured out how to test if the ball has collided with the rectangle and that works great. Now I need to determine which side of the rectangle that the ball has hit. I am currently trying this code (which works for testing the four sides but seems to have problems with the corners)...

```
if(Math.abs(ball.centerY-boundingBox.top) < ball.radius) {
    // Hit the top

}
else if(Math.abs(ball.centerY-boundingBox.bottom) < ball.radius) {
    // Hit the bottom

}
else if(Math.abs(ball.centerX-boundingBox.left) < ball.radius) {
    // Hit the left

}
else if(Math.abs(ball.centerX-boundingBox.right) < ball.radius) {
    // Hit the right

}
```

... Does anyone have any ideas how I can improve this? Or come up with a better solution for that matter?

I just basically need to determine which side a circle has hit on a rectangle after they collide. And I have already figured out how to test whether they collide or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It presumably doesn't work for corners because when the ball hits a corner, it hits two sides simultaneously. And if you're looking to make it bounce accurately, the relevant normal vector is that from the centre of the ball to the corner, which is going to be some diagonal between horizontal and vertical.

Assuming you always detect overlap while the centre of the ball is outside the rectangle, what you probably want to do is something like:

```
// is the ball above the box?
if(Math.abs(ball.ballCenterY-boundingBox.top) < ball.radius)
{
    if(ball.ballCentreX >= boundingBox.left)
    {
         if(ball.ballCentreY <= boundingBox.right)
         {
             // ball hit the top edge
         }
         else
         {
             // ball hit the top right corner
         }
    }
    else
    {
        // hit top left corner
    }
}
```

A better test — to handle both inside and outside collisions — would be to find distance to the closest point on each side, pick the smallest distance, then if closest point is a corner then its a corner collision, otherwise it's a side collision.

Comment: Your last comment about finding the closest point is how I'm currently doing my initial collision detection. I like your idea about testing if the closest point is a corner. Assuming it is a corner, do you have any idea how I would go about determining which side based on that? Assuming it isn't going directly toward the corner that is. Thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: There's no inherent side if it hits a corner because corners belong to two sides. However, if you need to pick one then — supposing you hit the top right corner — you'd probably pick the top edge if the vector from corner to sphere centre is closer to vertical, the right edge if it was closer to horizontal (so that's an compare on the absolute values of the x and y coordinates) and either without preference if it's exactly 45 degrees.

Comment: Ok so I have now made it so it picks a side when it hits a corner. Just one small issue that you may have some insight to... When the ball is rolling really slow across the top of the rectangle and it is about to fall off, when it reaches the corner it starts to get a little jumpy. It still follows the same general path, but just doesn't quite look right. Though the corners seems to be handled very well now so thank you for that.

Comment: You'd probably want to look into linear algebra and the dot product; that'll let you do bouncing off a face with an arbitrary angle. When you hit a corner you'd then use the vector from the corner to the centre as a normal for that bounce.

Comment: Sorry; the previous comment had been sitting on my screen for hours so I just hit send. I'm unsure about jumpiness; is it possible it's some sort of pixel collision issue?

Comment: Thanks I will look into getting the vector to bounce off of from the corners. That should be all I need to finish this. It is looking pretty good so far. As far as the jumpiness, I think all I need to do is detect when the ball has stopped bouncing and do not negate the y velocity when that happens.